# Modifying MYSQL query to get a JOIN between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm breaking my head trying to modify this query(thx sgeddes) in order to 
get at result not only from db_events.events fields, instead join it with some db_system.devices fields

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM db_events.events e 
   JOIN (
      SELECT Max(id) MaxId, device_id
      FROM db_events.events
      GROUP BY device_id ) e2 on e.Id = e2.MaxId AND e.device_id = e2.device_id
WHERE e.device_id IN (
            SELECT device_id 
            FROM db_system.devices 
            WHERE vendor = 1)
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```

How can I get it without repeat the subquery:

```
            SELECT * 
            FROM db_system.devices 
            WHERE vendor = 1
```

I need get `db_system.devices.brand` and `db_system.devices.model` joined with final results, and 
I tried to modify it step to step, I tried with temporary tables, I suspect it should be something simple, but I have not been able to do it, of course thank you very much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
SELECT  e.*, a.* 
FROM    db_events.events e 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT Max(id) MaxId, device_id
            FROM db_events.events
            GROUP BY device_id 
        ) e2 on e.Id = e2.MaxId AND 
                e.device_id = e2.device_id
        INNER JOIN db_system.devices a
            ON e.device_id = a.device_id  AND 
                a.vendor = 1
ORDER   BY e.id DESC
```

the condition `a.vendor = 1` can also be moved on `WHERE` clause and the result is still the same since you are using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT ....
FROM   .... JOIN ....
WHERE  a.vendor = 1
ORDER  BY ...
```

Comment: I think that's what he wants -- I just saw his comment on my previous answer -- thanks @JW!  +1

Comment: @JW,@sgeddes, Guys, I'm trying to understand it, how do you applied the logic to solve it? seems solving inside out...well, thanks a lot.

Comment: the subquery separately gets the maximum `ID` for every `device_id` on table `db_events.events`. the result of the subquery is then joined back on table `db_events.events` (*sort of self-join*) provided that it matches on `MaxID` and `device_id`. Then table partial result is then joined again on table `db_system.devices` so you can get the other values on which records have the same `device_id`